# Devise Token Authentication current_user is nil on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, null

I'm using devise and token_authenticatable and it works great locally; however, when I deploy to Heroku current_user returns nil and I get the following error: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'topics' for nil:NilClass)` when doing `current_user.topics`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user just wasn't logged in.